# "Recent Names" disappeared from Profile View

Tags: discussion, profile-page

Why did "Recent Names" disappear from the Profile View? Does this also mean that one can change the user name more often or are the restrictions on that still the same?

BTW: What was "Recent Names" good for?

Comment: Recent Names was good for determining MaX's current alias :)

Comment: Did it? I can however see it!

Comment: @Chaz: he was quite the Proteus, wasn't he? :)

Comment: @KannappanSampath It did. At least on my profile. Strange... maybe I'd change my name and see what happens...

Comment: @J.M. : *he still is...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why did "Recent Names" disappear from the Profile View?

It is still there; it only shows for your own account unless you are a moderator, and only shows if there is something to report - i.e. a name change in the last 90 days. Looking in history, it looks like it has always been this way, or at least since the user-profile pages were updated (4 months ago).

> Does this also mean that one can change the user name more often or are the restrictions on that still the same?

No; this is exactly the same

> BTW: What was "Recent Names" good for?

Making name changes visible, to yourself, and to moderators who may need to understand that you are also "ObnoxiousX", "AwesomeY" and "MediocreZ" (especially if there was a prior.... "discussion" with "ObnoxiousX").